# Почему не работает телеграм-бот с само подписанным сертификатом

Tags: python, nginx, telegram, openvpn

Хочу поднять телебота на домашнем компе(серый IP) для управления роутером из телеграма(для ограничения времени нахождения дочери в сети). Для этого сделал VPN tun с VPS. На VPS настроил nginx, который пробрасывает входящие в туннель. Сделал самоподписанный SSL сертификат, т.к. у меня доменное имя только на год бесплатно отказался от Let’s Encrypt, хотя с ним всё работало. Для проверки сделал второго бота на сервере с тем же сертификатом - всё работает. Подскажите, что может быть?

Comment: А почему кто-то должен доверять вашему самоподписанному сертификату?

Comment: Я  не правильно написал, второй бот на сервере работает с самоподписанным сертификатом. А на домашнем компе не работает.